# Application Loader Error 1095

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, application-loader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to process application info.plist validation at this time due to a general error (1095)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353049/unable-to-process-application-info-plist-validation-at-this-time-due-to-a-genera)

While uploading one of our applications to iTunes Connect with ApplicationLoader we get the following error:

```
Unable to process application Info.plist validation at this time due to a general error (1095)
```

I could not find any further information about this error code or how to solve this problem.