# Unable to process application info.plist validation at this time due to a general error (1095)

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, error-handling, app-store

I am creating a newsstand application. the application is ready, now i am trying to upload the app in apple store using Application Loader. While uploading the zip file its showing the error message as

> Unable to process application info.plist validation at this time due to a general error (1095)

[image]

I googled this in the net, but did not find the solution still.

Comment: As many others have mentioned below, we're experiencing this issue on 8/30/2012.  Just confirming since it appears to be a widespread issue today.

Comment: Look, we get it people, there's a server-side issue with Apple. Please stop posting "I'm having this problem, too" responses.

Comment: We have called apple and they are not aware of this issue so they are not currently solving it. Please call apple here https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.php

Comment: @over_optimistic Just talked to Apple. They're aware of it.

Comment: The problem has been reported in the Apple Developer Forum: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/165170?tstart=0

Comment: Two days already, I still got the same problem.

Comment: Having this issue now, 20140718. Heading for lunch. Better be fixed when I'm full.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This is clearly an Apple server issue, not an Xcode/iOS/OSX issue. Just wait patiently and Apple's servers will catch up to the traffic, or solve whatever issues they're having at their end.

If you're anxious, feel free to just sit there and restart Xcode until it works - but it's not restarting Xcode, only the time you waste that's solving the issue.

While you're waiting, run your apps in Instruments and solve some performance issues ;)

Comment: Has someone told them about this ?

Comment: Wanted to add that I was using Application Loader, so restarting Xcode is irrelevant.  My problem fixed itself without recompiling.  Don't mess about restarting things, just wait and try again later.  Massive upvote to the suggestion of how to spend that time :)

Comment: Didn't work for me all day, but I just tried again without any changes to the app, build, or system and it uploaded just fine.  This is apparently an intermittent issue - probably when things get congested.

Answer (score 31):

I just had this error. I waited an hour and tried again with the exact same build and it was all good. Vote for it being Apple's temporary glitch.

Comment: Happening again 31/8/12 @ 21:00 UK time.  I'm not even going to close Application Loader this time, just hit "Send" again occasionally.  Hopefully that will prove that it's nothing to do with restarting Xcode, restarting your Mac, doing a little dance, making a little love or getting down tonight... ;)

Comment: Now saying "due to an IO error".  Maybe not progress, but for those sweating this page, something is happening at Apple :)

Comment: And now working as expected.  I did not restart Application Loader, nor rebuild the package - just went to sleep and tried again in the morning.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. I closed Xcode, restart my computer and it worked.

Comment: Didn't need to restart the computer, but restarting Xcode did the trick.

Comment: Same as other users-- I had this problem today (8/30/12). Closing xCode and retrying did not work. Restarting OSX completely then resubmitting did work. (This was also 2 hours after I noticed the initial problem, so maybe it was fixed somewhere else in that time.)

Comment: Going to Force Quit and relaunching Finder did the trick for me!

Comment: I used application loader, not Xcode and waiting solved the problem for me. I think the time you wasted doing what you did solved the problem, not the actions you took.

Comment: This isnt the problem its a problem with their servers, I believe this was just coincidence

Answer (score 2):

One possible problem to this is corrupted png files. The png files should not be interlaced

Comment: It's true you have to be careful about this but this problem would appear after not during the info.plist thing

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to the problem.

If you're using Xcode 4+, you don't have to use Application Loader anymore. Instead you should archive your project in Xcode (Product->Archive). It will then open the organizer, where 3 buttons are displayed. Hit the submit button.

If you've created an entry for your app with Itunes Connect, you should be able to choose that from the list, and then select your distribution profile. Then hit the next button, and you should get a message, that tells you, that your app has been submitted.

At least that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

### Use Application Loader.

I'm getting this a lot today.

Application Loader worked.

```
XCode > Project > Archive
XCode > Organizer > Distribute > Enterprise/add Hoc > Save As
Saves as YOURAPP.ipa.
Make sure Save for Enterprise Deploy remains UNCHECKED.
Download latest Application Loader.
tap 'Deliver Your App'
make sure new version in itunes connect in WAITING FOR UPLOAD state
Click on Activity... button
```

---

TIP: open Console.app to see XCode Validation errors

```
Click on ALL MESSAGE on list of logs on right.
Then in search enter 'XCode' or 'Application Loader' 
to monitor any errors with your upload.
```

Note:

I did all this and still got email about missing 120x120 icons.

Forgot to update them in Build Target > General Tab
List of new icon requirements for iOS7
http://www.icenium.com/resources/forums/icenium-general-discussion/missing-recommended-icon-file

Answer (score 1):

Another reason why this can happen is the duplicate product name. Despite your app names, executable names, display names or bundle IDs are different, if the product name exists in your current apps this error is gonna occur.

Comment: could you develop this?

Answer (score 0):

"The server returned an invalid response. This may indicate that a network proxy is interfering with communication, or that Apple servers are having issues. Please try your request again later.""

Reset The internet connection. 
Reopen the xcode. 
Set the profile again. 
Clean build. 
And Archive the build.

Works perfect for me (With in 5 minutes no need to wait).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's just the time, because you can't control Apple's Server's traffic problem, We all merely become the victim of that..So cut the long story short...

By restarting XCODE may work but everyone as in my case, i tried by restarting XCODE, SYSTEM, ROUTER and anything and everything possible, only error name had changed from "The network connection was lost" to "The request timed out" and vice Versa..!

Just think at what time less people would be accessing the sever...

PS: Only perseverance can help you in this way..keep redialing..And WAIT and WATCH:P

Answer (score 0):

I solved ... :)

Please remove all your icons and splash image also remove icon Files and icons File( IOS 5 ) from info.plist and then add all your icons to app bundle ...

After this update info.plist iconFiles field add desired name of icons....

And last but not least remove Provisioning profile from developer portal and recreate it ...

Clean your build and Archive it and using Application Loader submit it to AppStore ...

it work for me and i think it may help you...

Not every time not it is Apple server issue,sometime we did some bad linking according to me :)