# Unable to process application plist validation

Tags: ios, validation, submit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to process application info.plist validation at this time due to a general error (1095)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353049/unable-to-process-application-info-plist-validation-at-this-time-due-to-a-genera)

I am getting the error

```
Unable to process application Info.plist validation at this time due to a general error.
```

I thought originally that this was a problem with Apple's servers, but I can validate a different app I am working on just fine.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353049/unable-to-process-application-info-plist-validation-at-this-time-due-to-a-genera) question, however I am already using XCode's archive and upload utility.  I really need to get this app uploaded, why would this fail validation, but run perfectly well?

EDIT:

Here is my xml for the plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>magichour.GIM-Conversion</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
        <dict>
            <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
            <false/>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>Handbook_icon_57.png</string>
                <string>Handbook_icon_114.png</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0.1</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
    <array>
        <string>Handbook_icon_57.png</string>
        <string>Handbook_icon_114.png</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string>MainWindow</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Did you use the latest Xcode (4.2.1) on Lion ? We have seen weird upload issues when using SnowLeopard and some older releases of Xcode.

Comment: Also, post the XML of your plist file here.

Comment: I am using xcode 4.2 on snow leopard, and I have added the xml to the question

Comment: Do you have any ideas? I'm still stuck on this

Comment: Restart OS and Xcode 3 times. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something must have been corrupted with the plist file, I created a new project, and copied the source code over, and I was able to upload

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12210232/730776

Answer (score 3):

I just had this error.  I waited an hour and tried again with the exact same build and it was all good.  Vote for it being Apple's glitch.

Comment: I have this error now. Waited 4hours but still without any better result. Will try again tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the creating new project thing but it didn't worked.

What worked was restarting my computer.

Comment: This worked for me too just now. I've never had that problem before.