# While uploading the binary on app store through xcode getting an info.plist errror

Tags: ios, info.plist

While uploading the binary on app store through xcode getting an info.plist errror.
http://screencast.com/t/nhZPC9ybj

Comment: What have you done to try to resolve this yourself?

Answer (score 3):

A lot of us are getting this right now. It appears to be an Apple issue. I've tried changing Info.plist settings, restarting Finder, rebooting, etc. and haven't been able to resolve it.

See: [Unable to process application plist validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390708/unable-to-process-application-plist-validation)

(An update: This was resolved on Apple's end after about 24 hours.)

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely an issue on Apple's end.  They are already aware of the problem and hopefully working on a solution.  In some cases, you may also see an "IO Error".  Be patient and try your submission again every few hours until the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried same way in next day.It works fine without giving any issue.Just wait for some time or try it on next day it will definitely work.