# The package does not contain an info.plist xcode upload issue

Tags: ios, xcode6, info.plist

I'm trying to upload an updated version of an old ios app to the app store.
I have tried xcode6.3.2 and applicationloader3.1
Each time I get the error

> "The package dose not contain an info.plist"

I can see the info.plist in the project, its not 'redded' out.

In build settings I have   $(SRCROOT)/myApp-Info.plist
And I can see myApp-Info.plist in the project.

In the identity section of target -> general - both versions set to 2.4

I am unable to post image of Info,plist : raw form

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
    <array>
        <string>icon.png</string>
        <string>icon@2x.png</string>
        <string>icon-small.png</string>
        <string>icon-small@2x.png</string>
        <string>iconipadrtn.png</string>
        <string>iconipad.png</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>CFBundleIcons~ipad</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.example.myApp</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>2.4</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>2.4</string>
    <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
    <string>public.app-category.medical</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string>MainWindow</string>
    <key>NSMainNibFile~ipad</key>
    <string>MainWindow-iPad</string>
    <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array/>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Would really appreciate some help -thanks!

Comment: Did you check if it is included in the bundle? Select the file in FileNavigator on the left and see in File Inspector on the right if your build target is checked.

Comment: Yes, I've change the name simply to Info.plist - its definitely in the package contants.

Comment: Did you also update the build settings accordingly?

Comment: In build settings I have $(SRCROOT)/Info.plist

Comment: this is driving me crazy - I wonder if it's related to this??   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216180/while-uploading-the-binary-on-app-store-through-xcode-getting-an-info-plist-errr?rq=1