# How upload my iOS / Mac OSX apps to iTunes Connect

Tags: xcode4.2, app-store-connect, application-loader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to process application info.plist validation at this time due to a general error (1095)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353049/unable-to-process-application-info-plist-validation-at-this-time-due-to-a-genera)

I can't find a way to upload my binary to iTunes Connect!
When trying to `Validate...` and `Submit...` in Xcode 4.2 i get this error:

```
Process:         Xcode [705]
Path:            /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         4.2 (828)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-828000000000000~138
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [145]

Date/Time:       2011-12-30 16:54:17.822 +0000
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.2 (11C74)
Report Version:  9

Interval Since Last Report:          43575 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           8
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  50931 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   8
Anonymous UUID:                      DCCB7B67-626D-402B-A527-69DFE00DD6DC

Crashed Thread:  13  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
```

And in Application Loader 1.3 i get this error:

> Unable to process application Info.plist validation at this time due to a general error (1095)

Contacted Apple DTS and still no reply!
How can I upload my binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED: I reinstalled Xcode and it gave a warning:

You need a 72X72 PNG image!

I did that and it worked i submitted it with Xcode 4.2.1!