# Xcode validation step as part of ad hoc distribution

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, ad-hoc-distribution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to process application info.plist validation at this time due to a general error (1095)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353049/unable-to-process-application-info-plist-validation-at-this-time-due-to-a-genera)

Over the past few weeks I've been distributing beta builds of my iOS app via ad hoc distribution. Everything was working fine until this morning 8/31/2012.

I followed the usual procedure in Xcode 4.3.3:

- Product => Archive
- Everything builds so far so good
- Click validate and choose the correct provisioning stuff in the wizard
- Validation fails immediately saying "Unable to process application info.plist validation at this time due to a general error"

I've tried to validate about ten times. Everytime it's the same thing. After reading [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353049/unable-to-process-application-info-plist-validation-at-this-time-due-to-a-genera) I feel confident it's an Apple problem. However I want to get this ad hoc build out to a client asap. Then it finally dawned on me: **Is the validation step in Xcode necessary when just doing an ad hoc build?**

Comment: Re-opened as this is not a duplicate. I haven't seen other questions addressing the ad hoc issue.

Answer (score 1):

I got this while trying to submit my app yesterday.  To fix it, I updated the icon files in my app and updated the plist.

I was missing my Icon-72.png

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Personally I does not validate IPA while ad hoc build, but do while submitting to App store. I recommend you should clean entire project using Alt + Cmd + Shift + k. Probably this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is should not be a case with adhoc builds(I myself uploaded adhoc build today 6 hours ago). Validation is not required to build for adhoc builds. Follow the below steps to get a clean adhoc build for your client.

**After generation of archive**
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hiding details of the client App

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately this didn't work when I tried it. I generated the ipa file. Then uploaded it to TestFlight. Then downloaded the app from the TestFlight email and it closes immediately after launching.