# "Unable to process application Info.plist validation at this time due to a general error"

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to process application info.plist validation at this time due to a general error (1095)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353049/unable-to-process-application-info-plist-validation-at-this-time-due-to-a-genera)

Is anyone still experience "Unable to process application Info.plist validation at this time due to a general error" for Application loader and/ or Xcode validation?

Comment: Yes, been trying to validate my app for the last 8 hours with no luck.