# unable to process application Info.plist validation at this time due to an IO error

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes-store, application-loader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to process application info.plist validation at this time due to a general error (1095)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353049/unable-to-process-application-info-plist-validation-at-this-time-due-to-a-genera)

For some time now, I've been trying to send an app to the App Store.  However, when I try to send it, it shows the progress indicator for about 1 minute and 30 seconds and then an error message comes up saying "Unable to process application Info.plist validation at this time due to an IO error".  I don't know what to do and I've spent hours fiddling with Info.plist trying to fix it.  Please Help!! :(

Comment: Aren't just Apple's servers down?

Comment: @user784044, I got the same error a little while ago.  I sent in an Email to iTunes connect and they called me by phone!  They told me it was their problem, that they were trying to work out.  But he never said when it would be fixed.  It wasn't your plist's fault!

Comment: Everyone, please stop asking this question and dumping "me too!" answers all over the site. All the information you need about this is in the duplicate question. I've had to remove over 50 posts about this just today. Complaining here won't make the issue go away, so have a little patience.

Comment: checked back just now and sent it in and it worked! :)