# Unable to process application Info.plist validation at this time due to a general / IO error

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to process application info.plist validation at this time due to a general error (1095)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353049/unable-to-process-application-info-plist-validation-at-this-time-due-to-a-genera)

The problem that started more than 12 hours ago now appears to be fixed.

Bug ID# 12218349 was lodged.

This message has been posted because the original post was locked so no-one could update it to let everyone else know that it may have been fixed.

Comment: I have been experiencing the same problem in last 12 hours or so. Fortunately, I have successfully uploaded my version a minute ago. It seems that Apple has fixed their server issue.

Comment: Great to hear. I was getting tired of cleaning up one question after another, along with all of the complaints, comments, and whatnot that was being posted all over the place. I've unlocked the original now that it's safe to do so.