# Getting error while uploading my iOS application

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7

[image]

I am trying to update my application for iOS 7, when i am trying to validate it i am getting this error in xcode 5.0 organiser. did any body else also have faced such problem any help will be appreciated .

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to process application info.plist validation at this time due to a general error (1095)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353049/unable-to-process-application-info-plist-validation-at-this-time-due-to-a-genera)

Comment: This does not look like Xcode5 specific issue, check link mentioned above.

Comment: well looks like i'll have to wait..

Comment: Try contacting Apple regarding the issue. They might be able to help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like there is some problem in apple server.

Comment: try rebooting your system

Comment: tried rebooting system and restarting xcode.. nothing working for me. i'm facing this issue for 2 days now. is there anything else i can try??

Comment: you can contact to apple developer support https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.php