# Project developed in earlier version of xcode are not being able to validate through Xcode 5.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I developed an application in xcode 4.6 after that when iOS 7 got launched application was crashing in that, so I downloaded xcode 5.0 ,I made changes, everything was fine until I tried to  upload application update to appstore .
While validating application through xcode organiser it is giving error as "Unable to process application info.plist at this time due to a general error. Please try again later"

[image]

But when I am trying to upload a simple test application developed in xcode 5.0, only then it is getting validated.Any help or if anybody else facing the same problem please reply

Thanks

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353049/unable-to-process-application-info-plist-validation-at-this-time-due-to-a-genera

Comment: i had seen this. but i am facing this problem since 7-8 days and i dont think that its because of apple server

Answer (score 1):

It seems the real issue is that XCode is unable to find a matching signing identity.Somehow the previously-created provisioning profile is not compatible or is not recognized.

You will have to create a New Provisioning Profile for Distribution to fix this issue.

Just go to the Apple's developer side and create a New Profile for your project and archive again with a new profile and it should work fine for you.

This also can help you.

Try refreshing Certs/Provisioning Profiles in the new XCode 5 Accounts

```
From XCode click > menu > Preferences > Accounts
Click on your Developer Account from list on the Left
View Details button on right
Pop down screen appears
Hit tiny refresh button on bottom left.
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I already tried creating new profile, new certificates but it didnt work :(

Comment: i hd tried all these things Manthan but thanks for the suggestion i dont know why nothings seems to work