# unable to process application info.plist validation due to a general error?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, app-store-connect

I know this question has been asked multiple times before and i looked into all answers.
I just want to confirm , anybody facing this issue today ?
Has someone submitted to app store today or yesterday without facing this issue . Just to make sure if others are facing this issue(seems to me due to apple servers).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly an Apple server issue, not an Xcode/iOS/OSX issue. Just wait patiently and Apple's servers will catch up to the traffic, or solve whatever issues they're having at their end.

If you're anxious, feel free to just sit there and restart Xcode until it works - but it's not restarting Xcode, only the time you waste that's solving the issue.

While you're waiting, run your apps in Instruments and solve some performance issues

[Unable to process application info.plist validation at this time due to a general error (1095)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353049/unable-to-process-application-info-plist-validation-at-this-time-due-to-a-genera)